# Why two classes can refer each other in JAVA?

Tags: java, memory-management

I see many examples illustrating one-one or many-many relationships in JAVA. But I still can not understand why this works.

if I have:

> class A(){B b = new B();}
>
> class B(){A a = new A();}

when I new A in main method as a start point, how JAVA allocates memory to handle this case?  would't memory-allocation be endless? A has b, then b has another A then `go on forever`

many thanks

further question:

can I do something like this instead?

> class A(){B b; public void setB(B bb){}}
>
> class B(){A a; public void setA(A aa){}}

Many thanks

Comment: Did you try to allocate an `A`? I suggest you do so, and I think you'll find your answer.

Comment: If it's a ONE-TO-ONE relationship, A has a B that has the same A so no infinite memory allocation.

Comment: @YassinHajaj No, it isn't.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch A little explaination doesn't hurt.

Comment: @YassinHajaj A [little explanation](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38036012/2970947) provided.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch This does not turn my explaination to false. A ONE-TO-ONE relationship exists between two elements only. No infinite concept in it.

Comment: They have unique instances of `A` and `B` (they aren't sharing them, so it's an *infinitely recursive* relationship).

Answer (score 3):

Java doesn't handle this situation<sup>**1**</sup>; if we correct the code and allocate an instance of `A`<sup>**2**</sup> (and make these classes `static` so we can embed it in a simple MCVE) we see something like

```
static class A {
    B b = new B();
}

static class B {
    A a = new A();
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    A a = new A();
}
```

Which, when executed, throws

> ```
> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StackOverflowError
> ```

<sup>**1**<sub>At *compile time*, it handles it at run-time by exhausting stack memory.</sub></sup>

<sup>**2**<sub>The same thing would happen if we tried to allocate a `B` instead.</sub></sup>

Comment: Many thanks, I add another case. Does the new case work?

Answer (score 0):

Unless those objects are static the program is gonna throw

```
java.lang.StackOverflowError
```

it can be easily be managed by making variables static which will lead to only 1 instance no matter how many times it is called and the memory wont overflow

well if u want something like this to work you can do it like this(But it isn't a good practice)

```
public class B {
static A a=new A();
}
public class A {
static B b=new B();
}
public class c {
public static void main(String[] args) {
A a=new A();
System.out.println("Task completed"+a);
}
}
```

Comment: Many thanks, I add another case. Does the new case work?

Comment: it wont work either as the memory allocation is still same old case so it will never finish the loop for allocating memory for any object declared in main